# Converting text to an array using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, arrays, selenium

I'm new to python and selenium and wondering how I could take a group of text from a web page and input it into an array. Currently, what I have now is a method that, instead of using an array, uses a string and un-neatly displays it.

```
# returns a list of names in the order it is displayed
def gather_names(self):  
    fullListNames = ""
    hover_names = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'recent-names')]") #xpath to the names that will need to be hovered over
    for names in hover_names:
        self.hover_over(names) #hover_over is a method which takes an xpath and will then hover over each of those elements
        self.wait_for_element("//div[contains(@class, 'recent-names-info')]", 'names were not found') #Checking to see if it is displayed on the page; otherwise, a 'not found' command will print to console
        time.sleep(3) #giving it time to find each element, otherwise it will go too fast and skip over one
        listName = names.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'recent-names-info')]").text #converts to text
        fullListNames += listName #currently adding every element to a string
return fullListNames
```

The output of this looks like

```
name_on_page1name_on_page2name_on_page3
```

without any spaces in between the names (which I would like to change if I cannot find a way to incorporate this into an array).

When I did try making fullListNames an array, I had issues with it grabbing each character of the string and the output looking something like

```
[u'n', u'a', u'm', u'e', u'_', u'o', u'n']....
```

Preferably, I need a format of

```
[name1, name2, name3]
```

Can anyone point in the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Both `fullListNames` and `listName` are strings. By the line `fullListNames += listName`, you are concatenating these two strings. Then all the names are concatenated into a single long string.

You just need to initialise `fullListNames` to an empty list: `fullListNames = []`. Then append `listName` to this list: `fullListNames.append(listName)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You are using string concatnation here ..
fullListNames += listName // thats the problem please refer below code i have replaced the selenium components you can add it depending upon your requirement.
also fullListNames should be an array
fullListNames =[]


def gather_names1():
    fullListNames = []
    #hover_names = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'recent-names')]") #xpath to the names that will need to be hovered over
    # #for names in hover_names:
    #     self.hover_over(names) #hover_over is a method which takes an xpath and will then hover over each of those elements
    #     self.wait_for_element("//div[contains(@class, 'recent-names-info')]", 'names were not found') #Checking to see if it is displayed on the page; otherwise, a 'not found' command will print to console
    #     time.sleep(3) #giving it time to find each element, otherwise it will go too fast and skip over one
    #     listName = names.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'recent-names-info')]").text #converts to text
    for i in range(10):

        listName="user"+str(i)
        fullListNames.append(listName)#currently adding every element to a string
    print fullListNames
    return fullListNames

gather_names1()
i got the below output
['user0', 'user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5', 'user6', 'user7', 'user8', 'user9']
```